# Create section in TableView from NSDictionary

Tags: uitableview

I am getting the table data from a server. It is a JSON data and every array is saved as a dictionary. I have an array of JSON objects.

The JSON is:

```
{
    sAlbum = Fallen;
    sArtist = Evanescence;
    sId = 1;
    sRate = 3;
    stitle = "Everybody's Fool";
},
    {
    sAlbum = Fallen;
    sArtist = Evanescence;
    sId = 2;
    sRate = 4;
    stitle = "Going Under";
}
```

and when I have it I use (with AFnetwrking)

```
[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
 // The success block runs when (surprise!) the request succeeds.
                                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

                                                    self.musicLibraryArr  = [(NSDictionary*)JSON  objectForKey:@"array"];


                                                    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"stitle" ascending: YES];
                                                    NSArray *sortedArray = [self.musicLibraryArr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

                                                    self.musicLibraryArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sortedArray];

                                                    self.loadingView.hidden = YES;

                                                    // partition
                                                    self.tableData = [self partitionObjects:self.musicLibraryArr collationStringSelector:@selector(self)];
                                                    NSLog(@"HEADER: %@", self.tableData);

                                                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                                                }
```

Now I am calling to self.tableData = [self partitionObjects:self.musicLibraryArr collationStringSelector:@selector(self)]; in order to create the section array

but I get the sections ass A to Z and in every section I have all the JSON data (the data repeat itself in every section instead of splitting the data to sections).

The partition method is:

```
-(NSArray *)partitionObjects:(NSArray *)array collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector
```

{
    UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
    NSInteger sectionCount = [[collation sectionTitles] count];
    NSMutableArray *unsortedSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];

```
for (int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++) {
    [unsortedSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
}

for (id object in array) {
    NSInteger index = [collation sectionForObject:[object objectForKey:@"sArtist"] collationStringSelector:selector];
    [[unsortedSections objectAtIndex:index] addObject:object];
}

NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sArtist" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];


for (NSMutableArray *section in unsortedSections) {
    NSArray *sortedArray = [section sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

//    collationStringSelector:selector]];
        [sections addObject:sortedArray];
    }

```
return sections;
```

}

Edit - #2
I initialised the data here:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
 // The success block runs when (surprise!) the request succeeds.
                       success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                      self.noMusicView.hidden = YES;
```

// Get the array of data from the json array
                                          self.musicLibraryArr  = [(NSDictionary*)JSON  objectForKey:@"array"];
                                          NSLog(@"JSON DATA: %@", self.musicLibraryArr);
                                         // sort the array
                                          NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"stitle" ascending: YES];
                                           NSArray *sortedArray = [self.musicLibraryArr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

```
                                        self.musicLibraryArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sortedArray];

                                        self.loadingView.hidden = YES;
                                         self.indexPathController.dataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:self.musicLibraryArr                                                   andSectionNameKeyPath:@"sTitle"                                              andIdentifierKeyPath:@"sId"];
```

//HERE I GET NULL (I check if I can see the data in NSLog)

```
                                                  NSLog(@"DATA MODEL %@", self.indexPathController.dataModel);

                                                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                                                }
 // The failure block runs if something goes wrong, such as when the network isn’t available. If that happens, you display an alert view with an error message.
                                                failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                 // Error view
                                 self.noMusicView.hidden = NO;
                                 self.loadingView.hidden = YES;
                                 self.noMusicViewLabel.text = error.localizedDescription;
                                                }];
```

Probably I am missing something in the partitionObjects method, please help

Answer (score 0):

You could try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958566/how-to-group-an-nsmutablearray-and-show-in-uitableview/16975075#16975075) using TLIndexPathTools. This approach saves you from having to manipulate the incoming data yourself. You just need to provide your array of dictionaries and a `sectionNameKeyPath`. See the example code.

**EDIT** Per your comment below, I added a sample project demonstrating a table view embedded in a `UIViewController` with minimal dependencies on TLIndexPathTools. Try running the [Minimal project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Minimal/Minimal/ViewController.m). The source of the view controller is as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "TLIndexPathController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <TLIndexPathControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) TLIndexPathController *indexPathController;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.indexPathController = [[TLIndexPathController alloc] initWithItems:@[
                                @"Chevrolet",
                                @"Bubble Gum",
                                @"Chalkboard"]
                                ];
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.indexPathController.dataModel.numberOfSections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.indexPathController.dataModel numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    NSString *title = [self.indexPathController.dataModel itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = title;
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - TLIndexPathControllerDelegate

- (void)controller:(TLIndexPathController *)controller didUpdateDataModel:(TLIndexPathUpdates *)updates
{
    [updates performBatchUpdatesOnTableView:self.tableView withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];    
}

@end
```

Using this as a base, you'd configure the data model as shown in the linked post.

**EDIT #2** The data model configuration would look something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.indexPathController = [[TLIndexPathController alloc] init];

    //if you get your JSON asynchronously, you would make the request after initializing
    //the index path controller, possibly right here. Assuming your JSON request
    //passes the result back through a callback block, the block would process
    //the incoming array like this block:
    ^(NSArray *jsonData){
        self.indexPathController.dataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:jsonData
                                                                   andSectionNameKeyPath:@"sTitle"
                                                                  andIdentifierKeyPath:@"sId"];
    };

    //or if you already have the data, just set the data model directly:
    self.indexPathController.dataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:jsonData
                                                           andSectionNameKeyPath:@"sTitle"                                                         
                                                           andIdentifierKeyPath:@"sId"];
}
```

If you need to update the data dynamically, just create a new data model as shown above and set the index path controller's `dataModel` property again. The controller will call its `controller:didUpdateDataModel` method and, as illustrated in the sample code above, the delegate will call `performBatchUpdatesOnTableView:` on the update object causing the new data to be animated in smoothly.

Comment: This class should be perfect but I need to use it with UIViewcontroller and in the examples they show that you need to use UITableViewcontroller. Do you know if I can use it by inherit from UIViewController?

Comment: The `TLTableViewController` class simply forwards to an instance of `TLTableViewDelegateImpl`, a class that provides minimal implementations of the `UITableViewDataSource` and `TLTableViewDelegate` protocols. You can hold an internal instance of `TLTableViewDelegate` in your view controller and use it in one of two ways: 1) The view controller is the table's delegate and it forwards messages to the `TLTableViewDelegate` instance as needed or 2) the `TLTableViewDelegate` is the table's delegate and you subclass it as needed to add/change delegate/data source logic.

Comment: Alternately, you can integrate an instance of `TLIndexPathController` directly into your view controller. The delegate/data source implementations would look like what you see in `TLTableViewDelegateImpl` except that you'd get the data model from the `TLIndexPathController` rather than a callback block. If it helps, I can add a sample project to demonstrate this. Its actually pretty simple.

Comment: I managed to compile it and show the data by doing: self.indexPathController = [[TLIndexPathController alloc] initWithItems:@[@"stitle]]; but as you said it is the data model, but in the first example I got the impression that it is the divider for the sections. where should I put the JSON array to show it with sections? thank you for the answer

Comment: The way it works in simple cases is you set your items on `indexPathController.items` and the controller creates a default data model for you. But if you need a non-default data model, such as if you need to specify `sectionNameKeyPath`, then you create your own data model, passing your items to one of the data model's initializers, and then set the data model on `indexPathController.dataModel`.

Comment: I get null after init the self.indexPathController.dataModel like in #2. I feel like I'm two minutes from solving it but still have no idea how

Comment: I have added the got where I get null - Edit - #2

Comment: A few things. Its hard to read your code because the formatting is messed up. But I do see that, if your data model is nil, it must be because your `indexPathController` property is also nil. I don't see the code where you set your `indexPathController`, so I can't say exactly why its nil. Also, you don't need to call `[tableView reloadData]` after updating the data model, assuming your view controller implements the TLIndexPathControllerDelegate method as I've outlined. The delegate method will perform batch updates on the table and you'll get a nice animated appearance.

Comment: You are right the code above is messed up I don't know why. I initialised the indexPathController as shown like you did in the example (edited 2) Do I need to init that object in a different way?

Comment: You just need to create indexPathController before you make the request (to ensure it's ready when the request completes). Or, you can lazy initialize the indexPathController, i.e. write the getter method to check for nil and initialize before returning the value.