# Section Headers and Row Content ... want them to display at the same time

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, networking, asynchronous

I have a table view that has section headers. I would like the row content and the section headers to display at the same time. Currently, they don't. I know WHY that is. I have to make a call to a server to get the data to populate the rows. By the time I have done this, the headers have already displayed themselves. My question is how do I get the headers to display themselves when the rows do?

If it matters, I'm using AFnetworking to do my networking calls. I'm using iOS 6.1, though I would like to support iOS 5 (again, if it matters).

Comment: Can't you just add sections you your data model when the network response comes back? Hard to be more specific without data model & view controller details.

Comment: How do you do the above? I have overloaded the function (NSArray* ) sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView to get the section headers. I assume that the app calls this function when it wants to display the headers. Now, the questions becomes how to get this method called at the "right" time.

Comment: I posted the answer yesterday. Are you good now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delegate methods need to take into account that data is coming in asynchronously. Lets assume for a moment that your data model consists of an array of sections, with each element in the array being a dictionary containing a title and an array of row data. Your `numberOfRowsInSection` would look like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [sectionsArray count];
}
```

So when `sectionsArray` is empty, the table view will know there are zero sections and nothing will be displayed. When your asynchronous data comes in, you populate `sectionsArray` and then call `[tableView reloadData]`. `numberOfRowsInSection` will be called again, this time returning non-zero number of sections and the table will populate itself.

All of this is easier to set up if you want to use a 3rd-party library like [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools). It can automatically organize your data into sections and provide a standardized data model with lots of convenience methods that help implementing delegate methods. Try running the [JSON](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/JSON/JSON/JSONTableViewController.m) sample project and [see my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261471/create-section-in-tableview-from-nsdictionary/17261683#17261683) about asynchronous loading

Comment: Actually, the problem was that the section headers were decided WAY before I actually got my data. So those were set up and displayed way before I actually got the data.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I said "can't you just add sections you your data model when the network response comes back?" in the comments.